# Getting warning when there is an unconnected IO in the design

Tags: chisel

I wonder if there is a way to get a warning when there is a module which I haven't connected one of its IOs. I'm generating verilog file from my chisel design. And in some cases, I can see that some of my IOs they are getting ripped out. I'm guessing the reason is that I have forgotten to connect them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [chiselTests/InvalidateAPISpec.scala](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/release/src/test/scala/chiselTests/InvalidateAPISpec.scala).  This is a new Invalidate API that is just being released. If that's not clear enough, I can put something together tomorrow, we haven't created a wiki page for it yet.

Comment: Thanks, what I needed. I need to figure out how it works though.

Answer (score 2):

As Chick mentions, we've just published a release candidate supporting the new Invalidate API - chisel3-3.0.0-RC1. Code is in the tip of both master and release branches. We've put together a [wiki page](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Unconnected-Wires) describing the new API and how to deal with the errors it may trigger.